# Did author David Mitchell have any influence on The Wachowski's TV series Sense 8?

Tags: reference, sense8, screenwriter

Netflix's [now canceled] TV series [Sense 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense8)  hails from film creator siblings known as [The Wachowskis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wachowskis) and follows a group of 8 characters across the globe whom become psychically linked, as they learn they are apart of what is called "a cluster" and later learn that they may also be super human or another kind of human.

> **The story of Sense8 begins when the psychic connection of eight
>   strangers from different cultures and parts of the world is "birthed"
>   by a woman called Angelica**, who kills herself to avoid capture by a
>   man named "Whispers". The eight eventually discover they now form a
>   cluster of "sensates": human beings who are mentally and emotionally
>   linked, can sense and communicate with each other, and can share their
>   knowledge, language, and skills.

The story format and and certain story elements are similar to a film they worked on previously, called ***Cloud Atlas***, which was adapted from the novelist David Mitchell's book of the same name. Anyone who has read Mitchell's work also knows that, much like Stephen King's *The Dark Tower* series, all of Mitchell's works exist in the same universe as revealed in a later novel ***The Bone Clocks***. Much like *Sense 8*, *The Bone Clocks* features similar ideas about reincarnation and a hidden super race living alongside humans, whom are engulfed in war.

> [The Bone Clocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bone_Clocks)
>
> The novel is divided into six sections with five point-of-view
>   first-person narrators. They are loosely connected by the character of
>   Holly Sykes, a young woman from Gravesend who is gifted with an
>   "invisible eye" and **semi-psychic abilities, and a war between two
>   immortal factions, the Anchorites, who derive their immortality from
>   murdering others, and the Horologists, who are naturally able to
>   reincarnate.**
>
> The title refers to a pejorative term that the immortal characters of
>   the book use to refer to normal humans, who are doomed to mortality
>   because of their aging bodies.

**With such similarities I was wondering if David Mitchell's works are a big influence on the *Sense 8* TV series.** Was he involved at all?

Comment: No offense, but have you done any research? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mitchell_(author)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I read a lot of reviews/interviews when it first came out and don't recall coming across his involvement, but then I was re-watching it and thought about it. Last time I went to DM's wikipedia (month or so ago) I don't recall that being there, but I see it is, so I will just make an answer then.

Comment: Unless you would like to make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, [David Mitchell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Mitchell_(author)) was involved! (Thanks to BCdotWEB for leading me to the answer)

> In 2015, Mitchell contributed plotting and **scripted scenes for the
> second season of the Netflix show Sense8**. Mitchell had signed a
> contract to write season three before Netflix cancelled the show. **He
> is credited as a writer on the Sense8 series finale special**.

And from Miguel Angel Silverstre's [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BZg6WKbgCQQ/?utm_source=ig_embed) revealing David Mitchell's name on a script.